# Delete similar rows

Tags: regex, excel, notepad++, vba

I have list of 3 word phrases with 90000 rows. I need to delete every row, if any other row contains 2 of the same words. For example

```
Word1 word2 word3
word1 word2 word4 - delete
word1 word2 word5 - delete
word1 word6 word7 - keep, only 1 matching words compared to earlier rows
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1.** Separate words into three columns (A, B, and C) using Text to Columns or formulas

**Step 2.** In columns D, E, and F, past the following formulas to create all two-word combinations:

```
=A1&B1
=B1&C1
=A1&C1
```

**Step 3.** Put the following formula in G1 and fill it through columns H and I and all the rows:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(OFFSET($D$1,0,0,ROW(D1),1),D1),COUNTIF(OFFSET($E$1,0,0,ROW(E1),1),D1),COUNTIF(OFFSET($F$1,0,0,ROW(F1),1),D1))-COUNTIF($D1:$F1,D1)
```

The spreadsheet should now look like this screenshot (besides the two rows I added to the end):
[image]

All rows with two words that match two words in a row above will have a value greater than 0 in columns G, H, or I.

**Step 4.** Finally, filter the entire table by rows G, H, and I equal to 0. You can copy and past (by value) the words to another sheet if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Are the three word phrases in separate cells or are they all in the same cell.

If they are in separate cells, you can use this macro:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DeleteDups()
    Dim colPhrase As Collection
    Dim colRows As Collection
    Dim V As Variant, vRes() As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim lDupCount As Long

    Dim rRes As Range 'results range

V = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1", Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
Set colPhrase = New Collection
Set colRows = New Collection

Set rRes = Range("e1")

'look for dups
For I = 1 To UBound(V)
    lDupCount = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    For J = 1 To 3
        colPhrase.Add Item:=CStr(V(I, J)), Key:=CStr(V(I, J))
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then lDupCount = lDupCount + 1
        Err.Clear
    Next J
    On Error GoTo 0
    If lDupCount < 2 Then colRows.Add Item:=CStr(I)
Next I

ReDim vRes(1 To colRows.Count, 1 To 3)
For I = 1 To colRows.Count
    For J = 1 To 3
        vRes(I, J) = V(colRows(I), J)
    Next J
Next I

Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes), 3)
rRes.EntireColumn.Clear
rRes = vRes

End Sub
```

If they are in the same cell, depending on how the phrases are separated, you would just need to add a line that separates them into three array elements.